# android app crashes on first attempt to share data using Facebook sdk in release mode

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I want the users to share some details from android app to Facebook wall. I am using facebook-android-sdk-3.6.0 for this.

I have configured the debug key and the release key in Facebook developer console and done the required changes in proguard-project.txt(for release build).
proguard-project.txt includes,

```
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
```

Now, the trouble I am facing here is, the share stuff works perfectly well in debug mode but, in release mode on the first attempt of share crashes the application. This happens on initial one or two attempts(which is again random, some time do not crash at all) after which this works good.

The error logcat is as below,

```
12-28 11:32:39.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13039): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-1
12-28 11:32:39.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13039): com.facebook.aq: com.facebook.c.f got an unexpected method signature: public abstract java.lang.Object com.facebook.c.c.a(java.lang.String)
12-28 11:32:39.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at com.facebook.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
12-28 11:32:39.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at com.facebook.c.f.b(Unknown Source)
12-28 11:32:39.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at com.facebook.c.f.invoke(Unknown Source)
12-28 11:32:39.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at $Proxy0.a(Native Method)
12-28 11:32:39.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at com.facebook.b.ab.a(Unknown Source)
12-28 11:32:39.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at com.facebook.b.ab.a(Unknown Source)
12-28 11:32:39.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at com.facebook.f.run(Unknown Source)
12-28 11:32:39.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by myself. For those, who might face this weird problem, It seems the problem was with Facebook-android-sdk-3.6.0. Spent hours to fix this, I tried version 3.5 also which again didnt help. Finally, I tried facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2 and it worked well. My app is up now and is available in google play :)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trident.holybible

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. So you simply fixed it by using 3.0.2 SDK? Do you know if it's fixed now for 3.7?

Comment: Yes. I used 3.0.2. Although, 3.6 gives better look and feel I chose to stick with 3.0.2. Unfortunately, I did not get chance to see if 3.7 works.